# Validate a String (PPS number)

Tags: java, string, loops

Okay, I'm trying to validate a String (in this case the PPS number). I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Here's the question:

> Each Irish citizen is allocated a PPS number once they reach the age
>   of 18 that is unique to them and used for taxation purposes. A valid
>   PPS number will have exactly 8 or 9 characters in total. It will begin
>   with exactly 7 digits and end with one or two uppercase letters. So,
>   for example, 1234567A would be considered a valid PPS number, as would
>   7863456RT, but 6478TY*%& and 8768086b would both be considered invalid
>   PPS numbers.

```
package Assess2013Two;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Group3Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int index = 0;
        char ch;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter your PPS number: ");
        String ppsNumber = input.nextLine();

        if(ppsNumber.length() >= 8 && ppsNumber.length() <= 9){
            if(ppsNumber.charAt(7) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(7) <= 'Z' && ppsNumber.charAt(8) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(8) <= 'Z')
            {
                if(ppsNumber.length() == 8) {
                    ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
                    while(index < ppsNumber.length() && ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
                        index++;
                        if(index < ppsNumber.length())
                            ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
                    }
                    if(index == ppsNumber.length())
                        System.out.println("You entered a valid PPS number.");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Invalid PPS number!! At least one of the first 7 characters were not digits.");
                }else {
                    ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
                    while(index < ppsNumber.length()-2 && ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
                        index++;
                        if(index<ppsNumber.length()-2)
                            ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
                    }
                    if(index == ppsNumber.length()-2)
                        System.out.println("You entered a valid PPS number.");
                    else
                        System.out.println("Invalid PPS number!! At least one of the first 7 characters were not digits.");
                }


            }else
                System.out.println("Invalid PPS number!! The second-last or last, or both, were not uppercase letters");
        }else
            System.out.println("Invalid PPS number!! It must contain at least 8 to 9 characters.");

        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use braces in your `if/else`, its confusing like that

Comment: In your while loop you are checking index < ppsNumber.length(), index is initialized to 6 and  ppsNumber.length() is 8 so ideally index is always less than ppsNumber.length(), you can probably change it to index < ppsNumber.length()-1 and start from index 0 instead.

Comment: @Gayathri I have tried that as well. It works in some cases but not for all the cases.

Comment: Can you specify which cases its failing?

Comment: you may also consider adding parenthesis in if((ppsNumber.charAt(7) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(7) <= 'Z') || (ppsNumber.charAt(8) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(8) <= 'Z'))

Comment: @Gayathri I added a revised version of the code. It works in all the cases except where the input is 8 characters. It gives me `string index out of range`

Comment: I think previous comment should help!

Comment: Second part of your if "&& ppsNumber.charAt(8) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(8) <= 'Z'" Do that only whne pps length is >8

Comment: @Gayathri still no joy :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems. The first that I found was this:

```
index = 6;
ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
while(index < ppsNumber.length() && ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
    index--;
    if(index < ppsNumber.length())
        ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
}
if(index == ppsNumber.length()-1)
    System.out.println("You entered a valid PPS number.");
```

Which is a String index out of bounds because you checking `index <` but you are decrementing. It should be something like this:

```
index = 6;
ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
while(index < 0 && ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
    index--;
    ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
}
```

And then this because you're decrementing:

```
if(index == 0)
    System.out.println("You entered a valid PPS number.");
```

Then you also get an out of bounds on this line if the entry is 8 digits long and the last digit is not an uppercase letter ("8768086b"):

```
if(ppsNumber.charAt(7) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(7) <= 'Z' || ppsNumber.charAt(8) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(8) <= 'Z')
```

Because it fails the first two checks and goes on past the `||`. This logic will also not work correctly for numbers with two letters at the end because only one has to pass. This is probably the most graceful way I can think of to 'inline' the entire statement:

```
if( ppsNumber.charAt(7) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(7) <= 'Z' &&

  ( ppsNumber.length() == 8 ||
    ppsNumber.charAt(8) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(8) <= 'Z' ) ) {
```

But that's looking pretty convoluted. See below where this is simpler if the conditions are reversed. Then you can split this in to two checks (which it really is).

After those changes it runs correctly for the inputs you've specified.

As a general style note you should try to write your code so you don't get so many indentations. You are doing a lot of this:

```
if (/* some check */) {
    /* indent and do a whole lot of stuff */

} else {
    /* it's not valid */
}
```

As well as resulting in a lot more indentations, if the code inside the if block is long then it's hard to tell what the else block refers to. Generally the following is cleaner IMO:

```
if (/* reverse the check */) {
    /* it's not valid */
    return;
}

/* do a whole lot of stuff */
```

This keeps your code neat and in line. For example see the following:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

try {
    String num = in.nextLine();

    if (num.length() < 8 || num.length() > 9) {
        System.out.println("it was invalid");
        return;
    }

    char check = num.charAt(7);

    if (check < 'A' || check > 'Z') {
        System.out.println("it was invalid");
        return;

    } else if (num.length() == 9) {
        check = num.charAt(8);

        if (check < 'A' || check > 'Z') {
            System.out.println("it was invalid");
            return;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        check = num.charAt(i);

        if (check < '0' || check > '9') {
            System.out.println("it was invalid");
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("it was valid");

} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

You also should not mix braced and non-braced if/else statements like this:

```
if (/*    */) {

} else
    /*        */;
```

It is very difficult to read. Pick one or the other, not both.

The same thing goes for "next line" and "end of line" bracing styles:

```
if (/*    */)
{
    while (/*    */) {

    }
}
```

Pick one or the other.

If you ask questions in the future you should also describe the specific problem you're having rather than just "doesn't work properly". "Doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything about how to help and some people are reasonably unwilling or unable to go run the program. Especially when there is stuff like exceptions involved. Post a stack trace and indicate the line that throws the error. It should be obvious to at least include that there is an exception at all and what kind.

Comment: This is working for all the cases except when I put the input as **1234567Pk**, it gives me a valid PPS.

Comment: It's an issue with the if condition that checks the last 1 or 2 digits. The `||` should be an `&&`. It's complicated by the necessity to check the length too but I updated my answer to show an expression which does both.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer regex for these types of issues.

```
if(ppsNumber.matches("\\d{7}[A-Z]{1,2}"))
{ 
  // valid
}
else
{
  //invalid
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `^` at the beginning of the regex and a `$` at the end?

Comment: I know regexp is a life saver, but unfortunately, I am not allowed to use regexp in this scenario. :(

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your `index` variable.  You have this loop:

```
index = 6;
ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
while(index < ppsNumber.length() && ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'){
  index--;
  if(index < ppsNumber.length())
  ch = ppsNumber.charAt(index);
 }
```

There's a few problems with this.  Your while loop makes sure that the index is smaller than the length of the PPS number.  Since the index only goes down, it will ALWAYS be smaller.  The last char that you want to check is index 0, so your loop should stop here.

Immediately after the loop, you have this code:

```
if(index == ppsNumber.length()-1)
  System.out.println("You entered a valid PPS number.");
```

This will never be true.  By this point, your code has checked that the PPS is the appropriate length.  `index` starts at 6 and can only get smaller, so index will never equal the PPS length minus one.

There are a few ways to fix this.  You could simply fix your fence post errors and change that if statement to make sure that `index` counted all of the way down.  The simpler way is to get rid of the if statement and adjust the loop like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
    char ch = ppsNumber.charAt(i);

    if(ch < '0' || ch > '9') {
      System.out.println("You entered an invalid PPS number.");
      return;
    }
}

System.out.println("You entered an invalid PPS number.");
```

This way, your loop exists as soon as it finds something wrong.  If you got through the loop, then you passed -- no extra check needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  if(ppsNumber.charAt(7) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(7) <= 'Z' && (ppsNumber.legth() =8 || (ppsNumber.charAt(8) >= 'A' && ppsNumber.charAt(8) <= 'Z')))
```